# How can i get all resources using a storage account in Azure using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to be able to get all resources using a particular storage account in Azure.
I am running the following command

```
Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "<resourcegroup>" -Name "<storage acct>"
```

but it doesnt give the service or resource using the storage account .

How can i get resources using a particular storage account , either in Powershell or Azure Portal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find out all the Azure Resources in a subscription which are using Azure Storage account to store logs or diagnostics data, you can leverage the below PowerShell script.

Note: Before running the sample ensure that you have the necessary Azure PowerShell modules installed. see below:

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts
Install-Module -Name Az.Resources
Install-Module -Name Az.Storage
```

After importing the above modules, you need to update the subscription ID in the below PS script:

```
# Login to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

# Select the concerned subscription ID
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId 'XXXXXXX'

Write-Output "`r`n"

 

# Get all resources in the subscription
$resources = Get-AzResource

 
# Loop through each resource and check if it has Azure monitor with storage diagnostic enabled
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    $resourceName = $resource.Name
    $resourceType = $resource.ResourceType
    $resourceId = $resource.ResourceId

 
    # Check if the resource has Azure monitor with storage diagnostic enabled
    $diagnosticSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $resourceId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($diagnosticSettings -ne $null -and $diagnosticSettings.StorageAccountId -ne $null) {
        # If it has Azure monitor with storage diagnostic enabled, get the storage account name
        $storageAccountId = $diagnosticSettings.StorageAccountId
       # $storageAccountName = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resource.ResourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountId.Split("/")[-1]).StorageAccountName

        # Output the resource name and storage account name
        Write-Output "$resourceId of Type ($resourceType) has Azure monitor with storage diagnostic enabled. Storage account ID: $storageAccountId"
        Write-Output "`r`n"
        
    }
}
```

More Info [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-CXP-Developer-Support/tree/main/Storage/Blob/Powershell/ListAzureResourceUsingStorageAccount).

Comment: can it output which storage account is not used as well ?

Comment: diagnosticSettings is empty for all storage accounts. I know for a fact that some should not be empty

Comment: Please note the above powershell script is to list the Azure resources which are using your Storage Accounts. It will display that resource and the corresponding storage account.

The diagnostic settings on your storage account might be (can be) empty. That is fine.

Comment: ok , so out of about 30 storage accounts the script outputs only 1 as being used . Thanks for the script